# How can i split the value of a select box option and pass it in two different input fields using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my code:

```js
$(".dropdowncitymenu").change(function () {
    $("#sCity").val($(this).val());
    $("#sRegion").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-size:12px;margin-bottom:20px;">City Field
<input placeholder="CITY" class="input-text" type="text" id="sCity" />
</div>
<div style="font-size:12px">Region Field
<input placeholder="REGION" class="input-text" type="text" id="sRegion"/>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:20px;width:100%;display:block;">
<select id="dropdowncities" class="dropdowncitymenu">
<option value="">Select a Location...</option>
<option value="Los Angeles (California)">Los Angeles (California)</option>
<option value="Miami (Florida)">Miami (Florida)</option>
</select>

</div>
```

How can i make it using jquery or even plane javascript, so when i select a location from the select box, to pass the city into the city input field and the region into the region input field accordingly ?

Comment: Split string by opening parenthesis. Everything at index 0 is city and everything (minus closing parenthesis) is the region. If you can control how the drop downs are created then it is better to e use data attribute to store the region separately. Or use a delimiter to separate city and region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to separate the city/state in the `value` attribute by a single character which you can then `split()` 
to create an array. Then you can set the elements of the resulting array as the values of the text fields. In the example below I used `,` as the delimiting character, but anything will work so long as it won't be used within a value itself. Try this:

```js
$(".dropdowncitymenu").change(function() {
  var location = $(this).val().split(',');
  $("#sCity").val(location[0]);
  $("#sRegion").val(location[1]);
});
```

```css
#container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#city {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#region {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="city">City Field
  <input placeholder="CITY" class="input-text" type="text" id="sCity" />
</div>
<div id="region">Region Field
  <input placeholder="REGION" class="input-text" type="text" id="sRegion" />
</div>
<div id="container">
  <select id="dropdowncities" class="dropdowncitymenu">
    <option value="">Select a Location...</option>
    <option value="Los Angeles,California">Los Angeles (California)</option>
    <option value="Miami,Florida">Miami (Florida)</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Also note that I placed the CSS rules in to an external stylesheet. You should avoid inline styling where possible.